# Stack build fails with LLD errors

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, lld

I'm trying to build some Haskell packages with `stack` (`haskell-ide-engine` and `hlint` specifically), but they both fail with many `ld.lld` error messages, all related to `R_X86_64_32S` relocation, e.g.:

```
ld.lld: error: can't create dynamic relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol: stg_bh_upd_frame_info in readonly segment; recompile object files with -fPIC or pass '-Wl,-z,notext' to allow text relocations in the output
>>> defined in /home/kas/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-8.6.5/lib/ghc-8.6.5/rts/libHSrts_thr.a(Updates.thr_o)
>>> referenced by /home/kas/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.o:(s6WS_info)
```

I tried configuring `stack` to use a different linker (using `ghc-options` flags), but I can't get that to work, and it always uses `lld`.

Does anyone know how I can change `stack`'s linker, or fix the error some other way?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the key point is the `-fPIC` flag

Comment: Thanks! How/where should I set that flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/faq/#i-get-strange-ld-errors-about-recompiling-with-fpic) answer in `stack`'s own FAQ!